# Возведение в степень sqlite

Tags: sqlite, sql

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите какая функция возводит число в степень в sqlite. Стандартные pow/power не поддерживаются

Comment: SO [говорит](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190064/how-to-find-power-of-a-number-in-sqlite), что такой функции нет, и ее надо создавать через `sqlite3_create_function()`.

Answer (score 1):

Тут найдёте ответ: [How to find power of a number in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190064/how-to-find-power-of-a-number-in-sqlite)